# In gmock, Is there a way to have mock object return an instance of an user defined object?

Tags: googlemock

For UT purposes, I am trying to Mock out a function that returns a vector of user defined structs.

```
std::vector<myStruct> myClass::foo()
```

In gmock, Is there a way to do something like this:

```
 std::vector<myStruct> TestVector;
 //code to populate my vector ....

 ON_CALL(MockMyClass, foo()).WillByDefault(Return(TestVector))
```

I couldn't find anything in the gmock cookbook, it looks like the return values are all primitives. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using ReturnPointee

https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Returning_Live_Values_from_Mock_Methods

```
std::vector * ptr;

//instantiate and populate vector...

ON_CALL(MockMyClass, foo()).WillByDefault(ReturnPointee(ptr));
```

Comment: What's the problem with using the `Return` action? Just make sure your class has a default constructor and a copy constructor.